# Grub Customizer Error when launching on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, customizer

I'm getting the error below when I am trying to use Grub Customizer on Ubuntu

> grub-customizer: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libatkmm-1.6.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I am not sure where exactly what has gone wrong as I only installed Ubuntu today.

- Legovil

Comment: try this " sudo apt install libatkmm-1.6-* " from command line

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error when launching grub-customizer in ubuntu 18.04, what I did was just find the path of the missing library:

```
    $ sudo find / -name "libatkmm-1.6.so.1"
    /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatkmm-1.6.so.1
```

after that, I included the lib directory to the file that configures the libs environment variable:

```
    $ sudo su
    # echo "/snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
    # ldconfig
```

and it worked.

### ----------

OR you can create symbolic links into an already default lib path:

```
    sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatkmm-1.6.so.1.1.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatkmm-1.6.so.1
    sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangomm-1.4.so.1.0.30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangomm-1.4.so.1
    sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 
    sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1.4.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1
    sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0
    sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1.3.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1
```